# NUTCH: How to make take.screenshot and screenshot.location property work?

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04, nutch

I have been learning Nutch (version Nutch-1.14) since a week and is working fine in local mode as well as with Hadoop-2.7.2 (pseudo distributed mode). Today I came across "take.screenshot", "screenshot.location" properties in nutch-site.xml, after modifying these properties nutch is crawling the seed urls but is not taking the screenshots in local mode as well as with Hadoop.

**nutch-site.xml setting for local mode**

```
<property>
 <name>take.screenshot</name>
 <value>true</value>
 <description>
  Boolean property determining whether the protocol-htmlunit
  WebDriver should capture a screenshot of the URL. If set to
  true remember to define the 'screenshot.location'
  property as this determines the location screenshots should be
  persisted to on HDFS. If that property is not set, screenshots
  are simply discarded.
 </description>
</property>

<property>
 <name>screenshot.location</name>
 <value>/home/user/nutch-1.14/screenshot</value>
 <description>
  The location on disk where a URL screenshot should be saved
  to if the 'take.screenshot' property is set to true.
  By default this is null, in this case screenshots held in memory
  are simply discarded.
 </description>
</property>
```

**nutch-site.xml setting for Hadoop**

```
<property>
 <name>take.screenshot</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>screenshot.location</name>
 <value>/screenshot</value>
</property>
```

**Note** "screenshot" directory is present in HDFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable the `protocol-selenium`? Basically, this will only work with this protocol, by default Nutch uses the `protocol-http` plugin which doesn't support this option, even if you enabled those settings in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs" (see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). This means, HtmlUnit does not render the html page at all. Internally all the operations are done based on the dom tree without any layouting. This is the reason why there is no option to take a screenshot.